# How to access index file in Block Themes?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm new to wordpress code and read that `index.php` is located in the `root/themes/yourtheme/index.php`.

When I open `index.php` in the `twentytwentytwo` folder in my wordpress directory, it sais that `block themes do not use php templates`:

[image]

Where do I find the file with `<head>` and `<body>` tags etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant file is located in `wp-includes/theme-compat/header.php`